# Page dirty bit clear in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to write to a user-space memory through my kernel driver and I had a problem that the bytes I wrote to that memory were eventually saved into the disk (And I did not want em to be).
To solve the issue, I cleared the dirty bit of the page I wrote to.

```
disable WP @ CR0
copy_to_user(some_user_addr, some_kernel_addr, some size);
enable WP @ CR0
get_user_pages(...);
ClearPageDirty(page);
```

Here's what happens now:

If I close that user program and look at its Elf file content, it seems that the things I wrote are actually still there - Looks like the dirty bit clearance did not work.

BUT, when I restart my computer, it seems that the things I wrote are not there! - Looks like the dirty bit clearance did work.

My assumption is that there's one more level of storage/caching/what ever 
which means that when the content actually needed to get written to the disk, it did NOT because I cleared that page's dirty bit. But that dirty bit clearance did not affect the writing to the current 'instance' of the file in that level of storage.

So, the bottom line is:

How can I achieve my goal? How can I force the operating system to not change the original file at all (after I write to it through my kernel driver)?

Comment: May be when you tried to read the contents it read from the cached page from memory. And not from the the some sort of second level disk cache you are thinking.

Comment: Okay. How can I remove that cached page from memory? :[

Comment: Try `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` after you close the user program and before you read its elf

Comment: I only modify code (Text section).

Comment: Being readonly memory it is likely that the same physical pages will be mapped into all processes. There's not much you can do about that because your driver is tricking the system by writing to a readonly page. You may consider other approaches such as getting your driver to copy out the original pages, make your changes and then modify the user mappings so that they see the new pages instead of the original ones.

Comment: That might be a good idea. How do I do that? I can not do that by simply change the address corresponding pte I suppose..

Comment: I'm running into the same issue when i'm modifying the text segment but when i'm modifying the text segment for a mapped library of the process i don't get the same issue, It's really odd as i've tried clearing the TLB using  `flush_tlb_all()` and `clflush_cache_range()` but nothing actually works.